# Adding Heredoc syntax Highlighting in VSCode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, erb

I have a Rails project in which I'm using View Components. Inside most components, I have a `erb_template` HEREDOC which defines the components markup using ERB templated HTML.

When I set the HEREDOC opening tag to HTML (uppercase only), I get html syntax highlighting. Likewise, if I set it to RUBY, I get ruby syntax highlighting and so on.

I'm struggling to find where I can configure this kind of embedded syntax highlighting and add ERB support. Has anyone done this successfully?

[image: Example of component]

Comment: Framework challenge: Why use a HEREDOC at all instead of extracting the template out into a seperate `.erb` file?

Comment: On larger components, using a separate template file is nice and cleans up the component dentition (RB) file. However, for more compact components, it's nice having a single file handle all concerns. This is obviously purely a developer preference.

Answer (score 0):

See this github issue which discusses adding more languages to the heredoc: https://github.com/Shopify/vscode-ruby-lsp/issues/820

I believe you can change `grammars/ruby.cson.json` and submit a PR to vscode-ruby-lsp. The file used to be at https://github.com/atom/language-ruby/ but I believe that repo looks locked/archived.